# How to solve "no matching index found." error

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I created a sample app `guestbook-foo` in App Engine.

It works fine in `localhost:8080`, but when I deploy the project, I get a "no matching index found." error.

```
API error 4 (datastore_v3: NEED_INDEX): no matching index found. recommended index is:
- kind: Greeting
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: Date
    direction: desc
```

In the project directory there is a `index.yaml`

```
indexes:
- kind: Greeting
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: Date
    direction: desc
```

I think I must upload the index file to the server. But I couldn't find out where I should specify the file. How can I configure `gcloud app deploy` option? Or is there another way to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ironsand is right, you can use `gcloud app deploy app.yaml index.yaml` when the indexes were not uploaded directly.

However, you should always check first if they are being updated or not because sometimes it takes a while for Datastore to build the indexes. To check for this go to the App Engine console > Datastore > Indexes and check if the index in being built. If it is still building, this error will keep occurring until the Datastore finishes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it from the console next time.

Answer (score 1):

I had to specify `index.yaml` when deploying.

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml index.yaml
```